# query by missing value in Applescript

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to query contacts in Outlook that don't have a first name. I know they exist as can be seen by:

```
return (first name) of every contact whose (company = "SomeCompany")
```

returns: {missing value, "Francesca", missing value, missing value, missing value}

But I want only those where the first name is missing value. So I tried:

```
return (first name) of every contact whose (company = p_companyName and (first name is missing value))
```

But Applescript doesn't like that:missing value can't be converted to text" number -1700 from missing value to text

so my next attempt is:

```
return (first name) of every contact whose (company = p_companyName and (first name is missing value as text))
```

which runs fine, but doesn't return any records, which is incorrect. So what might be the correct way here?

Comment: Have you tried `(first name = "")` or `((first name as text)'s length = 0)`

Comment: The first version (first name = "") I did try, but it would not find any records. The 2nd version I tried right now, but Applescript chokes again (error 1700 cannot convert to text). I guess it does that when it tries to convert one of those missing value entries to text. Thanks.

Comment: Outlook is a beast to script.  You may be stuck with developing an iteration handler to process everything individually.  Good luck.

Comment: Why are you returning the first name of every contact whose first name is missing value? You're just getting a list of (missing value, missing value,…). Is what you're wanting actually a list of contact references? Then first pull the ones matching p_companyName, then repeat iterate through those and pull every contact whose name is missing value.

Comment: I am sorry for this, this is just due to me lazily pasting my test scripts. If the result contained a list of just missing values I would know my script is working. I am interested in the contacts themselves.

Comment: Okay, so I will iterate over those contacts. Thanks.